# input string was not in correct format, but dont know why

Tags: c#, mysql, string-formatting

In my C# app I am reading numeric data from my MySQL table. After that, I am searching for  a minimal euclidean distance (between table row and an average tuple).

I am reading values from MySQL table into double variables (`f1` to `f8` and one `int` variable). I am getting this error on the **first line**, where I am putting the reader's result into `f1`. However, when I do random computation after reading my values for example (`f1`+`f8`), it returns right/exact result. So why does C# have a problem with the input string?

Here is my code:

```cs
for (int k = 1; k <= pocet; k++)
{
    string queryCompare = " SELECT F1 AS Fe1, F2 AS Fe2, F3 AS Fe3, F4 AS Fe4, F5 AS Fe5, F6 AS Fe6, F7 AS Fe7, F8 AS Fe8, cluster FROM features WHERE ID=" + k;
    MySqlCommand cmdCompare = new MySqlCommand(queryCompare, conect);
    readerCompare = cmdCompare.ExecuteReader();
    readerCompare.Read();
    //  MessageBox.Show("OK");
    double f1 = Convert.ToDouble(readerCompare["Fe1"].ToString());  // EXCEPTION HERE
    double f2 = Convert.ToDouble(readerCompare["Fe2"].ToString());
    double f3 = Convert.ToDouble(readerCompare["Fe3"].ToString());
    double f4 = Convert.ToDouble(readerCompare["Fe4"].ToString());
    double f5 = Convert.ToDouble(readerCompare["Fe5"].ToString());
    double f6 = Convert.ToDouble(readerCompare["Fe6"].ToString());
    double f7 = Convert.ToDouble(readerCompare["Fe7"].ToString());
    string f88 = readerCompare["Fe8"].ToString();
    double f8 = Convert.ToDouble(f88, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    int cluster = Convert.ToInt32(readerCompare["cluster"].ToString());

    readerCompare.Close();
    //  MessageBox.Show((f1+f8).ToString());

    switch (cluster)
    {
        case 1:
            euklDist = (double)Math.Sqrt(
                                        Math.Pow(touple[0, 0] - f1, 2) + 
                                        Math.Pow(touple[0, 1] - f2, 2) + 
                                        Math.Pow(touple[0, 2] - f3, 2) + 
                                        Math.Pow(touple[0, 3] - f4, 2) + 
                                        Math.Pow(touple[0, 4] - f5, 2) + 
                                        Math.Pow(touple[0, 5] - f6, 2) + 
                                        Math.Pow(touple[0, 6] - f7, 2) + 
                                        Math.Pow(touple[0, 7] - f8, 2));

            if (euklDist < minCl1)
            {
                minCl1 = euklDist;
                idCl1 = k;
            }
            break;

        case 2:
            euklDist = (double)Math.Sqrt(
                                        Math.Pow(touple[1, 0] - f1, 2) +
                                        Math.Pow(touple[1, 1] - f2, 2) +
                                        Math.Pow(touple[1, 2] - f3, 2) + 
                                        Math.Pow(touple[1, 3] - f4, 2) + 
                                        Math.Pow(touple[1, 4] - f5, 2) +
                                        Math.Pow(touple[1, 5] - f6, 2) +
                                        Math.Pow(touple[1, 6] - f7, 2) +
                                        Math.Pow(touple[1, 7] - f8, 2));

            if (euklDist < minCl2)
            {
                minCl2 = euklDist;
                idCl2 = k;
            }
            break;

        case 3:
            euklDist = (double)Math.Sqrt(
                                        Math.Pow(touple[2, 0] - f1, 2) +
                                        Math.Pow(touple[2, 1] - f2, 2) + 
                                        Math.Pow(touple[2, 2] - f3, 2) +
                                        Math.Pow(touple[2, 3] - f4, 2) +
                                        Math.Pow(touple[2, 4] - f5, 2) + 
                                        Math.Pow(touple[2, 5] - f6, 2) + 
                                        Math.Pow(touple[2, 6] - f7, 2) + 
                                        Math.Pow(touple[2, 7] - f8, 2));

            if (euklDist < minCl3)
            {
                minCl3 = euklDist;
                idCl3 = k;
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Records in my db are in this format:

- from f1 to f7: `xx,xxx`
- f8: `xx.xxx`

I know that `f8` has decimal point instead of comma that is why I am using `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` for `f8`.

Comment: What is the value of `readerCompare["Fe1"].ToString()` exactly? And what is your `CurrentCulture`?

Comment: @SonerGönül In column f1 I have approximately 400 values. Here are the first four: 91,08; 399,02; 445,76; 60,57. The same format is used in columns f2,f3,f4,f5,f6,f7. I dont really know why, but for f8 is is like this: 457.935; 452.72; etc. My current culture is sk-SK

Comment: @user2179427, is it failing on the first record?

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud When the exception is thrown, the line where double f1 is, is highlited

Comment: @user2179427, the value of the row is **exceptionally** important here. What's the *value of the row* when it fails?

Comment: Have you tried this? Convert.ToDouble(readerCompare["Fe1"].ToString(), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)

Comment: any chance to be a problem with the decimal separator? (,) maybe it is expecting another char (.) ...

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud Sorry, but I do not really know where can I find out number of the processed row. Can you point me please?

Comment: @user2179427, when the debugger breaks, add this expression to the Watch window `readerCompare["Fe1"].ToString()`.

Comment: @June Paik: bad idea: '.' is decimal separator in invariant culture but it has to be ',' according to value format (xx,xxx)

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud Now I get it. In my table I have some null cells. Now I have to figure out how to update my table to put 0 to the null cells.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to *update* the `null` values, just do this:

```
Convert.ToDouble(readerCompare["Fe1"]);
```

The `null` will be handled by `ToDouble` and convert it to its default value; `0`.

See, here is the `ToDouble` implementation you'd be using with the above code:

```
public static double ToDouble(object value)
{
  if (value != null)
    return ((IConvertible) value).ToDouble((IFormatProvider) null);
  else
    return 0.0;
}
```

**UPDATE:** alright if you also need to support empty strings then you'll have to change this code a little. First let's build an extension method. Create a new `class` in your solution and name it `SystemExtensions`, then paste in this code:

```
namespace System
{
    public static class SystemExtensions
    {
        public static string ToConvertibleDouble(this object input)
        {
            var s = input as string;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s.Trim())) { return null; }

            // this will also take care of the separator
            return s.Replace(".", ",");
        }
    }
}
```

and now let's use it:

```
Convert.ToDouble(readerCompare["Fe1"].ToConvertibleDouble());
Convert.ToDouble(readerCompare["Fe2"].ToConvertibleDouble());
...
Convert.ToDouble(readerCompare["Fe8"].ToConvertibleDouble());
```

Comment: Same exception, but now the watch window says this:  +  Convert.ToDouble(readerCompare["Fe1"]); 'Convert.ToDouble(readerCompare["Fe1"])' threw an exception of type 'System.FormatException' double {System.FormatException}

Comment: @user2179427, you get the same exception **after** removing the `ToString()` call in the code?

Comment: @user2179427: what's the value of `readerCompare["Fe1"]` in the Watch window? Further, are you ***100% sure*** this is the ***same row*** failing?

Comment: In watch window I have column "Name", where it says:"Convert.ToDouble(readerCompare["Fe1"]);", in column "Value" it says: "'Convert.ToDouble(readerCompar‌​e["Fe1"])' threw an exception of type 'System.FormatException'". So I dont really know if we are talking about the same window, or if I am understanding you correctly.

Comment: @user2179427, add a new watch expression and use this `readerCompare["Fe1"]` as the expression. Then tell me the value.

Comment: value is "" and type is object {string}

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52391/discussion-between-michael-perrenoud-and-user2179427)